# How to add a field at a fixed position in Blackberry?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I am curious to see if it's possible to display a `Field` at a fixed position on the screen and at the bottom most layer so any other `Manager` or `Field` paints over it, except the background of the `Screen`. As if that field is added to the background of the `Screen`, but is displayed on top of the actual background that can be set using `Screen.setBackground()`. Is there any specific `Manager` that can achieve this? Or a combination of them? As far as I can see there can't be overlaps between `Manager` layouts. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a custom manager that does this.   It would have two Java fields of type Field, plus an XYRect to keep track of the positioning for the fixed field.

Then in the sublayout method, set the position for your fixed field and layout the overlay field.
And in the subpaint method, make sure your fixed field is painted first, then the overlay field gets painted on top.

When using your custom manager, the second field can be anything, such as another manager.  This solves your overlapping manager problem.

You didn't say whether you wanted special focus behavior, but your custom manager could take care of that too, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout [AbsoluteFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/AbsoluteFieldManager.html)